# Confusing Inline Assembly

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, att, osdev

```
static inline void
insw(int port, void *addr, int cnt)
{
    asm volatile("cld\n\trepne\n\tinsw"
             : "=D" (addr), "=c" (cnt)
             : "d" (port), "0" (addr), "1" (cnt)
             : "memory", "cc");
}
```

Hey guys, I am feeling kinda confused about this code snippet while I was reading the code. I was wandering cnt looks like a loop counter, why it is not stored into ECX straightly but use "1" as input constrain. Seems like we can save one more register. I am new to this area, leave me few more steps if I made any newbie mistake. Cheers.

Comment: `1` means use the same location as operand `1` which is `=c(cnt)` so it **is** `ecx`. Could have used `c` directly as well, or a read-write operand. Same result, different syntax.

Comment: Wow, I was busy trying to figure out which weird architecture had `trepne` and `tinsw` instructions. Man, I feel a bit of a goose now :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Maybe, "Confusing inline assembly" would've been a proper title as well... (Tapped into same trap.)

Comment: @Jester Based on what I know, I can save the line for output operands, right? Cuz I can basically do the job on the line for input operands all together.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The only thing I can think of is to convert `addr` and `cnt` to read-write operands but those belong in the output list.

Comment: Just use `"+D"(addr), "+c"(cnt)` ; RMW operands are simpler than matching constraints, and this is a wrapper function so it's ok to modify those C variables.  You're doing so anyway by using them as outputs.  You can't "save registers" ; [`repne insw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ins:insb:insw:insd) implicitly uses 3 registers; they must all be set on input.  I'd suggest using `; ` as a separator instead of `\n\t`  for readability between insns.

Comment: You might like to separate the instructions into their own string literals like this: `"cld" "\n\t" "repne" "\n\t" "insw"` if you want them on multiple lines in the listing.

Comment: @thebusybee And if multiple lines are not that important, it's often more legible to separate them with semicolons: `cld; repne insw`

Comment: Given the calling convention requires DF=0 upon entry to a function the `CLD` isn't required.

Comment: I will assume you are working with MIT's JOS operating system.